# Nested For Loop ignores Arrays of GLines from ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

It seems like Java is ignoring one of my for loops that's nested in the following code: (Java only adds the last Array of GLines from the ArrayList arrayListGLines - and not all Arrays from the same ArrayList). Thanks to anyone who can help!

```
GLine[] decadeLines = new GLine[NDECADES]; // instance var
ArrayList<GLine[]> arrayListGLines = new ArrayList<GLine[]>(); // instance var
...
private void graph() {

    String entryString = database.findEntry(nameField.getText()).toString(); 
    entryString = entryString.replace("[", "");
    entryString = entryString.replace(",", "");
    entryString = entryString.replace("]", "");
    NameSurferEntry entry = new NameSurferEntry(entryString); 
    entry.getName();

    for (int i = 0; i < NDECADES - 1; i++) {
        decadeLines[i] = new GLine(i * (getWidth()/11), GRAPH_MARGIN_SIZE + entry.getRank(i) * (getHeight() - (2 * GRAPH_MARGIN_SIZE)) / MAX_RANK, (i + 1) * (getWidth()/11), GRAPH_MARGIN_SIZE + entry.getRank(i + 1) * (getHeight() - (2 * GRAPH_MARGIN_SIZE)) / MAX_RANK);
        // sorry for the redundancy
        //add(decadeLines[i]);          
    }

    arrayListGLines.add(decadeLines); 

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayListGLines.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arrayListGLines.get(i).length - 1; j++) { 

            System.out.println("arraylistsize " + arrayListGLines.size());
            GLine[] arrayGLine = arrayListGLines.get(i);
            add(arrayGLine[j]);
            ////add(arrayListGLines.get(i)[j]); alternative
            if (i == 3) { // just trying to access the 3rd GLine[] of arrayListGLines
            add(arrayListGLines.get(2)[3]); //- can't access this element's object which is a GLine
            add(arrayListGLines.get(2)[4]);//- can't access this element's object which is a GLine
            add(arrayListGLines.get(2)[5]);//- can't access this element's object which is a GLine
            System.out.println("OK");} // been trying to debug that's why i have this
        System.out.println(i + " " + j);// been trying to debug that's why i have this

        }
    }
```

Comment: Whats up with that add method?

Comment: Please show us your `add()`-method. It's possible that the problem is located there. Usually Java never makes errors. It's always the programmer who does. ;)

Comment: I've edited the code. Thank you.

Comment: I haven't been getting exceptions or errors but I can't make Java do what I want which is to display or add in the canvas all the lines that are contained in Arrays inside the ArrayList. Only the last ith Array is added to the canvas. Thanks!

Comment: @JR We need to see the `void add(GLine g){ ... } ` method, as mentioned above, the problem may come from this method.

Comment: Sorry, all the add methods are just due to the declared arrayListGLines ArrayList instance variable for dynamic addition of array elements. I didn't make any add methods. Thank you.

Comment: Does this even complie? So maybe you should use `arrayListGLines.add(GLine g)` if that is what you are trying to do? Where does the `void add()` method come from, and what are you trying to do with it.

Comment: The add() method comes from here: void add(GObject gobj) which is from this doc: https://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/jtf/javadoc/complete/acm/program/GraphicsProgram.html

Comment: In the code, I was adding the Array of GLines to the ArrayList through this part: arrayListGLines.add(decadeLines);

Comment: It does compile but I can't make it do the things that I needed it to do like. I'll have a good look again at the code and documentation too. Thank you.